# How to Change row order in UITableView in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have List called "myplaces" with Name,Image,co-ordinates and distance.
I bound my list with table view in viewdidload  method. I am also using Pull to refresh control to update my table view but I am able to update only cell e.g. image,name,etc. I want to change row order by Distance property to get the nearest place first in table view. i am updating my list order like below. Please help me.

```
myPlaces = myPlaces.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ToList();
```

here is the code

```
UITableView table;
    RrefreshTableSource tableSource;
    bool useRefreshControl = false;
    UIRefreshControl RefreshControl;
    double PlaceRadius = 100;
    public Places selectedplace;
    AppDelegate appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    public static LocationManager Manager { get; set; }

    public PlacesViewController(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        if (appDelegate.myPlaces.Count == 0)
        {
            Places p = new Places();
            appDelegate.myPlaces = p.LoadPlaces();
        }

        Manager = new LocationManager();
        Manager.StartLocationUpdates();
    }
    public override async void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveDidBecomeActive((sender, args) =>
        {
            Manager.LocationUpdated += HandleLocationChanged;
        });
        UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveDidEnterBackground((sender, args) =>
        {
            Manager.LocationUpdated -= HandleLocationChanged;
        });

        Title = "Places";
        table = new UITableView(new CGRect(0, 20, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height - 20));
        tableSource = new RrefreshTableSource(appDelegate.myPlaces,this);
        table.Source = tableSource;
        table.RowHeight = 80;
        await RefreshAsync();

        AddRefreshControl();
        Add(table);
        table.Add(RefreshControl);

    }
    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        //var indexPath = table.IndexPathForSelectedRow;
        var indexPath = (NSIndexPath)sender; // this was the selected row
        if (segue.Identifier == "detailsview")
        {
            var placedetail = segue.DestinationViewController as PlacesDetailViewController;
            placedetail.selectedplace = appDelegate.myPlaces[indexPath.Row];
        }
    }
    public void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle foreground updates
        CLLocation location = e.Location;
        Manager.currentLocation = location;
        //if (Manager.point != null)
        //{
        //  double curdistance = location.DistanceFrom(Manager.point);
        //  lblfarfrom.Text = "Far from " + Math.Round((curdistance), 2).ToString() + " meters";

        //}
        CalcNearLocation(Manager.currentLocation);
        //Manager.pointregionname = tbMessage.Text;
        //Console.WriteLine("foreground updated");
    }
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    }
    async Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        if (useRefreshControl)
            RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing();

        if (useRefreshControl)
            RefreshControl.EndRefreshing();

        table.ReloadData();
    }
    #region * iOS Specific Code  
    void AddRefreshControl()
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0))
        {

            RefreshControl = new UIRefreshControl();
            RefreshControl.ValueChanged += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                CalcNearLocation(Manager.currentLocation);
                await RefreshAsync();
            };

            useRefreshControl = true;
        }
    }

    public void CalcNearLocation(CLLocation currentLocation)
    {
        if (appDelegate.myPlaces != null && appDelegate.myPlaces.Count > 0)
        {
            CLLocation closestLocation = null;
            double smallestDistance = double.MaxValue; 
            string placename = string.Empty;
            foreach (Places place in appDelegate.myPlaces)
            {
                CLLocation location = new CLLocation(place.points.Latitude, place.points.Longitude);
                double distance = currentLocation.DistanceFrom(location);
                place.Distance = ConvertMetersToKiloMeters(distance);

                if (distance < smallestDistance)
                {
                    smallestDistance = distance;
                    closestLocation = location;
                    placename = place.Name;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Closest Location " + placename);
            Manager.pointregion = new CLCircularRegion(closestLocation.Coordinate, PlaceRadius, placename);
            Manager.pointregionname = placename;
            appDelegate.myPlaces = appDelegate.myPlaces.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: do you invoke ReloadData method after the sorting? Can you show more code?

Comment: @iamIcarus updated question with code.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the global variable items on `appDelegate.myPlaces` but your are not updating the items that are inside the source of the TableView.

You will need to do something like this on your `RefreshAsync` method

```
async Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        if (useRefreshControl)
            RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing();

        if (useRefreshControl)
            RefreshControl.EndRefreshing();

        // Update the items inside the source , then reload data
        ((RrefreshTableSource)table.Source).Items = appDelegate.myPlaces; 
        table.ReloadData();
    }
```

If `Items` (or whatever is the name of the variable for the items in the source ) is not public you will need to expose it